# How to declare variable containing character limiting to 1000 bytes in vb6

Tags: vb6

How to declare variable containing character limiting to 1000 bytes in vb6

Comment: 1000 bytes is example only..
I want a variable of charater type which can store upto certain no . of bytes only

Comment: I don't think VB6 has a "char" variable type. Have a look here at the different types: http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Variables_and_Types_in_VB6.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean bytes or characters? A VB6 character is **two** bytes.

Answer (score 9):

```
Dim myString as String * 1000
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the syntax for a fixed-length string of 500 *characters*, which is 1000 *bytes*. [VB6 strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212271(office.10).aspx) are [Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (UTF-16) and therefore each character has **two** bytes. The value of a fixed-length string will always have 500 characters - trailing spaces will be added, or excess characters truncated.

```
Dim s As String * 500  ' 500 characters, 1000 bytes
```

I wonder whether you are dealing with binary data rather than text. The [Byte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220031.aspx) data type is better for binary data.

```
Dim byt(1000) as Byte  ' an array of 1000 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough approximation. 
It assumes you are flexible with that 1000 byte limit.

```
Private mData As String
Public Property Let Data(value As String)

    If Len(value) <= 1000 Then
        mData = value
    Else
        'Do whatever '
    End If

End Property
```